# What is the ideal way to write and initial model in an angularjs application

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering what would be the right way to create and initialize a model in a angularJS application.

THE WAY I AM DOING IT RIGHT NOW IS BY CREATING A SERVICE THAT INITIALIZES A MODEL.

```
 //FOLLOW.JS
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app').service('Follow', function(Gateway, $q, $auth, User) {
var FollowModel = function FollowModel(initValue) {
  var __ = {
    facebookId : null,
    players: [],
    fans: []
  };

  _.merge(__, initValue);

  Object.defineProperty(this, '__', {value: __});

};

Object.defineProperty(FollowModel.prototype, 'facebookId', {
  get: function() { return this.__.facebookId;},
  enumerable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(FollowModel.prototype, 'players', ... 
 .. details here
});


FollowModel.prototype.followPlayer = function(facebookIdToFollow) {
  ... details here
};

 var followService;
return {
  init : function(data) {
    followService = new FollowModel(data);
  },
  model : function() {
    return followService;
  }
};
```

The initialization happens when the user logs in:

//APP.JS

```
$stateProvider
        .state('core', {
          abstract: true,
          template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
          resolve: {

            authInfo : function($auth) {
              return $auth.authenticate('facebook');
            },

            followList: function(Follow, Gateway, User, authInfo) {

              var promise = Gateway.getFollowInfo();
              promise.success(function(data) {
                Follow.init(data);
              });
              return promise;
            }

          }
        })
        .state('home', {
          parent: 'core',
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html'
        })
```

Is there a better way to initialize this ?
Is there a way to separate the model from the service ?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are having? What does `separate model from service` mean?

Comment: I am trying to establish good data modelling practices in my application.. separating model from services means.. should the model be sitting in a sepeate file and the service then initiating it ?? or is what I have already a good approach